# Assign value of a column to variable in sql use jinja template language

Tags: sql, jinja2, etl, dbt

I have a sql file like this to transform a table has a column include a json string

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

with customer_orders as (
  select
    time,
    data as jsonData,

{% set my_dict = fromjson( jsonData ) %}
{% do log("Printout: " ~ my_dict, info=true) %}

  from `warehouses.raw_data.customer_orders`

  limit 5
)

select *
from customer_orders
```

When I run `dbt run`, it return like this:

```
Running with dbt=0.21.0
Encountered an error:
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Undefined
```

I even can not print out the value of column I want:

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

with customer_orders as (
  select
    time,
    tag,
    data as jsonData,

{% do log("Printout: " ~ data, info=true) %}

  from `warehouses.raw_data.customer_orders`

  limit 5
)

select *
from customer_orders
```

```
22:42:58 | Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
22:42:58 | 
Printout: 
22:42:58 | Done.
```

But if I create another model to printout the values of jsonData:

```
{%- set payment_methods = dbt_utils.get_column_values(
    table=ref('customer_orders_model'),
    column='jsonData'
) -%}

{% do log(payment_methods, info=true) %}

{% for json in payment_methods %}
{% set my_dict = fromjson(json) %}
{% do log(my_dict, info=true) %}
{% endfor %}
```

It print out the json value I want

```
Running with dbt=0.21.0
This is log

Found 2 models, 0 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 372 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 0 sources, 0 exposures

21:41:15 | Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
21:41:15 |

['{"log": "ok", "path": "/var/log/containers/...log", "time": "2021-10-26T08:50:52.412932061Z", "offset": 527, "stream": "stdout", "@timestamp": 1635238252.412932}']

{'log': 'ok', 'path': '/var/log/containers/...log', 'time': '2021-10-26T08:50:52.412932061Z', 'offset': 527, 'stream': 'stdout', '@timestamp': 1635238252.412932}

21:41:21 | Done.
```

But I want to process this jsonData with in a model file like `customer_orders_model` above.

How can I get value of a column and assign it to a variable and continue to process whatever I want (check if in json have a key I want and set it value to new column).

Notes: `My purpose is that: In my table, has a json string column, I want extract this json string column into many columns so I can easily write sql query what I want.`

Comment: what database are you using?
do you want it to print every json object in the column?

Comment: My database is BigQuery, I want some column in json or if you can auto parsing keys and values in json, that 's great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case BigQuery database, Google has a [JSON functions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions)

If your column is JSON string, I think you can use `JSON_EXTRACT` to get value of the key you want

EX:

```
with customer_orders as (
  select
    time,
    tag,
    data as jsonData,
    json_extract(data, '$.log') AS log,
  from `dc-warehouses.raw_data.logs_trackfoe_prod`
  limit 5
)
select *
from customer_orders
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close! The thing to remember is that dbt and jinja is primarily for rendering text. Anything that isn't in curly brackets is just text strings.

So in your first example, `data` and `jsonData` are a substring of the larger query (that is also a string). So they aren't variables that Jinja knows about, which explains the error message that they are `Undefined`

```
with customer_orders as (
  select
    time,
    data as jsonData,
  from `warehouses.raw_data.customer_orders`
  limit 5
)
select *
from customer_orders
```

This is why `dbt_utils.get_column_values()` works for you because that macro actually runs a query to get the data and your assigning the result to a variable. the [`run_query` macro](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) can be helpful for situations like this (and i'm fairly certain  `get_column_values` uses `run_query` in the background).

In regards to your original question, you want to turn a JSON dict into multiple columns, I'd first recommend having your db do this directly. Many dbs have functions that let you do this. Primarily jinja is for generating SQL queries dynamically, not for manipulating data. Even if you could load all the JSON into jinja, I don't know how you'd write that back into a table without using something like a `INSERT INTO VALUES` statement which, IMHO, goes against the design principle of dbt.